# sp_addlinkedserver syntax

Tags: sql-server

I would like to make a copy of what's on my remote server at xxx.safesecureweb.com.
How do I connect to it from my local SQL Server?

Is the syntax something like:

```
sp_addlinkedserver 
@server='PRODUCTION', 
@provider='xxx.safesecureweb.com',
@Username='myUsername', 
@Password='myPassword'
```

What I'm thinking of doing is writing a bunch of insert statements like:

```
INSERT INTO Test.Table
SELECT * FROM Production.Table
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You do not specify the remote user and password in the linked server definition. Linked servers have a separate object that mapps the login of users connected to the local server (the 'locallogin') with remote logins. See [Security for Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175537.aspx). For example, the following maps all local logins on the linked server to the specified MyUserName SQL Login:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver 'xxx.safesecureweb.com';
exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'xxx.safesecureweb.com'
    , 'FALSE', NULL, 'myUserName', 'myPassword';
```

You can only map with user/password a remote **SQL** login. Remote Windows logins (trusted authentication) must use integrated authentication and configure the server for [constrained delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739587%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Provider should be the client provider you want to use to connect. @datasrc is the servername to connect to.

```
sp_addlinkedserver  
@server='PRODUCTION',  
@provider='SQLNCLI', -- sql native client.
@Username='myUsername',  
@Password='myPassword',
@dataSrc = 'xxx.safesecureweb.com'
```

Then, when querying, I believe you need to use a four part name fot the table:

```
INSERT INTO Test.Table
SELECT * FROM Production.mydatabase.dbo.Table
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: Thanks Paul.
I added the two parameters @Username and @Password because I know I need to supply them somewhere to something.  But they're not in the sp_addlinkedserver list of parameters.

Comment: Ah yes - doh! You'd need to use sp_addlinkedsrvlogin to add the login: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx